# Azure billing on Microsoft hosted agents and parallel jobs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

We recently started our journey with new azure DevOps environment. I really need detailed billing document for Microsoft hosted agents and Parallel jobs on pay-as-you go.
What are the advantages with Microsoft hosted agents on self hosted agents and cost  for this all. Is there any email contact of Microsoft azure billing support. please someone help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can check pricing for Azure DevOps here --> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I can see only pricing of parallel jobs. Where I can find pricing of Microsoft hosted agents. Please let me know in details.